# Convert pyplot figure into wand.image Image

Tags: python, matplotlib, wand

Is there a way to convert a pyplot figure created with `pyplot.Figure` into a wand image? I have tried using the following to no avail:

```
image_data = BytesIO()
figure.savefig(image_data, format='png')
image_data.seek(0)
image = Image(file=image_data, resolution=250)
```

The end goal of this is to convert a list of figures into a long png. The only other method (which is ugly) is to convert to pdf and then concatenate the pages.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure out how to do this same thing. I went down a rabbit hole for a bit thinking I needed to also use PIL (Pillow) to accomplish this task. With the help of the previous answer I was able to come up with a complete example:

```
import matplotlib
from io import BytesIO
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wand.display import display
from wand.image import Image

plt.plot([1,5,3,2])
plt.ylabel('y axis numbers')
plt.xlabel('x axis numbers')

image_data = BytesIO() #Create empty in-memory file
plt.savefig(image_data, format='png') #Save pyplot figure to in-memory file
image_data.seek(0) #Move stream position back to beginning of file 
img = Image(file=image_data) #Create wand.image
display(img) #Use wand to display the img
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are on the right track. Without seeing the figure, I would assume the issue would be related to [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) holding the C structure pointer using the `with` keyword.

```py
image_data = BytesIO()
figure.savefig(image_data, dpi=250, format='png')
image_data.seek(0)
with Image(file=image_data) as img:
    # ... do work
    img.save(filename='/tmp/out.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the recommended code above and had no luck.  I posted the question to the WandB forum ([here](https://community.wandb.ai/t/matplotlib-into-wandb/3212/2)) and the following was recommended:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(...)
...
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
buf.seek(0)
wandb.log(({"chart": wandb.Image(Image.open(buf)) }))
fig.show()
```

It seems that using the `file` parameter is no longer allowed.